# unicode rendering in android notification

Tags: android, html, unicode, android-notifications

consider a unicode which can be converted into html escaped form like: & #65; I want to display emoticons and emoji in the notification. Hangouts is able to do it for some emoticons.

Can android notification render html?
any work-around?

Answer (score 0):

MAybe use Html class;

```
String text = Html.fromHtml(<your string>);
```

Comment: Which charset do you use?